# How to get pandas to act like MS Excel with cell arithmetic?

Tags: python, pandas

**Objective:** Have a function placed at a given position within a Pandas dataframe that updates with adjustments in the dataframe

**Description:** I am trying to subtract 75,000 from 400,000 to result in 325,000 and have it be displayed in a Pandas datframe. Currently, the row 'End Cash' provides me all the answers that I am expecting. However, these are hard coded values and not dynamic.

```
import pandas as pd

data_2 = [['Init Cash', 400000, 325000,335000,355000,275000,225000,240000],
          ['Matur CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['Interest',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['1-mo CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['3-mo CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['6-mo CDs',0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          ['Cash Uses',75000,-10000,-20000,80000,50000,-15000,60000],
          ['End Cash', 325000,335000,355000,275000,225000,240000,180000]]

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2,columns=['Month', 'Month 1', 'Month 2', 'Month 3', 'Month 4', 'Month 5', 'Month 6', 'End'])
df_2_copy = df_2.copy()
```

I thought I could get away with something like the following:

```
df_2_copy.iloc[7]['Month 1'] == (df_2_copy.iloc[0]['Month 1'] - df_2_copy.iloc[6]['Month 1'])
```

But, unfortunately, this does not work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want something reactive I would look into Dash DataTable by Plotly: https://dash.plot.ly/datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index by column `Month`, so possible subtract only numeric columns selected by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df_2_copy = df_2_copy.set_index('Month')
df_2_copy.iloc[7] = df_2_copy.iloc[0] - df_2_copy.iloc[6]
print (df_2_copy)
```

Which would produce:

```
           Month 1  Month 2  Month 3  Month 4  Month 5  Month 6     End
Month                                                                  
Init Cash   400000   325000   335000   355000   275000   225000  240000
Matur CDs        0        0        0        0        0        0       0
Interest         0        0        0        0        0        0       0
1-mo CDs         0        0        0        0        0        0       0
3-mo CDs         0        0        0        0        0        0       0
6-mo CDs         0        0        0        0        0        0       0
Cash Uses    75000   -10000   -20000    80000    50000   -15000   60000
End Cash    325000   335000   355000   275000   225000   240000  180000
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select rows by labels:

```
df_2_copy.loc['End Cash'] = df_2_copy.loc['Init Cash'] - df_2_copy.loc['Cash Uses']
```

If row not exist, then is created new one with [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement).